# Withdrawn: Ask for confirmation when making a tag synonym suggestion

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, confirmation

<s>Pretty straight forward request.  Just ask for a confirmation when suggesting a tag synonym.</s>

I was browsing the different tag synonyms for various tags and accidentally *suggested* a tag when I thought I was searching for one.  An honest mistake that easily could have been prevented.

Not really an important issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly against this, for two reasons. First, I think it's probably extremely rare that this happens, and (not to be rude) I'm not sure how you can miss that this is an interface for suggesting a synonym:

[image: Screenshot of the tag synonym box]

Second, I thoroughly dislike sites and programs that constantly prompt you to make sure you haven't made a mistake; it's largely a waste of time. If we're not going to prompt people for confirmation before closing or deleting posts, we certainly shouldn't for something as minor as proposing a tag synonym, which (if it's bad) will just get downvoted and end up having no effect whatsoever

---

I downvoted the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/synonyms), so it's halfway to being deleted

Comment: It was C# -> .net or the other way around.  I would have liked it if I could have removed it myself.

Comment: I understand your point and I agree.  But in my defense, the [tag browsing](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) page has a text field to search for a tag.  It didn't have the same meaning when looking at the tag synonyms page.  Its presence made me think they behave similarly.